# I want to find data from firebase data base like this by using query. if input are matched with stored data then show mobile number

Tags: firebase-realtime-database

I want to find data from firebase data base like this if(name=="name 1" && age == "age 1" && birth date =="birth date 1"). then show mobile number , how can i face data from firebase by and check it[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oT1cz.png)

Answer (score 0):

Firebase Real-time Database does not support multiple equal queries so at a time you can use only one equalTo() query of the firebase database so try to apply the field here which breaks your data in the best manner so that you receive the least data to process at your side.

And finally you can apply your rest two equal queries at the backend in the received data to get the desired result.